# Чебурашка и чебурахнуться

Tags: этимология

Насколько я помню сказку, Чебурашку назвали так за то, что он часто падал (чебурахался). А вот откуда взялось сами слово "чебурахнуться"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если поверите без ссылок (думаю, что все можно найти при наличии желания и времени, а у меня сейчас нет ни того, ни другого), то дело обстоит так.

Успенский в сказке слегка погрешил против истины. Диалектное слово "чебурахать" и производное "чебурашка" в русском языке существуют в нескольких значениях. Одно из них, очень близкое к использованному (падать, валиться), существует где-то в Нижнем Поволжье. Чебурашка - игрушка наподобие Ваньки-встаньки.     
Успенский, отстаивая свои авторские права на героя, уверял, что слова этого при написании сказки не знал. Но как-то не очень убедительно. В другой раз поведал, что, будучи где-то в гостях, услышал от совсем маленькой девочки, как кто-то или что-то (щенок?) чебурахнулся, и это слово ему очень понравилось. 
Если сопоставить эти два утверждения, получается, что Успенский приписал девочке изобретение слова. Но сходство значений уж очень подозрительно.  
Т.е. сомнительно, что маститый писатель не догадался, что ребенок явно слышал слово от взрослых. А при таком сходстве значений - даже очень сомнительно.

Comment: И всё высовывался из гнезда, всё разглядывал.

- Чадо, чадо, - беспокоилась мать, - смотри - чебурахнешься!

- Чем, чем? - спрашивал Пудик.

- Да не чем, а упадешь на землю, кошка - чик! и слопает! - объяснял отец, улетая на охоту. ( М.  Горький.  Воробьишко )

Comment: Да! Кстати, Горький - это таки Поволжье. Хотя и не южное.

Comment: — Ну, кланяйтесь же, и вон! — красноречиво заключил генерал. Николашка с Палашкой чебурахнулись еще раз в ноги и вышли. Герцен, Кто виноват?
— Понимаете… мостовой переход обвалился… Весь чебурахнулся к черту. Гладков, Энергия.